# Python, BeautifulSoup - Can't get specific element's text without its siblings as well

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm a bit of a novice here, so please forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to get a line of code to return just on specific tag's elements. The problem is, my approaches yield these respective results...:

```
for items in soup.find('td', text='Trading Symbol').parent.find_all('td'):
ticker = [items.text.strip()]
print(ticker)

['Trading Symbol']
['AAPL']
['']
```

and

```
    for items in soup.find('td', text='Trading Symbol').parent.find_all('td'):
    for td in items.find('td', {'class':['text']}):
        ticker = [td.text.strip()]
        print(ticker)

....error message....for td in items.find('td', {'class':['text']}):
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I understand why the first code does what it does-I've not specified exactly what I'm after (the stock ticker AAPL), but I don't know why adding one additional line of code specifying the class doesn't narrow the list down. By looking at the soup (which I've provided below) I figure the additional line of code would remove 'Trading Symbol' and leave 'AAPL' and '[]' but it comes up with nothing. Any help here?

Here's the soup. There are hundreds of "re" class tags so filtering using that may be helpful but it won't be the end-all.

```
##      <tr class="re">
##      <td class="pl " style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_dei_TradingSymbol', window );">Trading Symbol</a></td>
##      <td class="text">AAPL<span></span>
##      </td>
```

Comment: Where is the closing for the `tr` tag?

Comment: please check your html against the source and use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert the html as a direct formatted copy paste. Also, include url if possible. I think there are a number of issues with the html above.

Comment: Also, is it not  {'class':'text'} rather than {'class':['text']} and you are already at the level of td when you try to call again - bad juju.

Comment: The closing is there, just didn't include it in the original post. The hmtl is pulled directly from the url... it hasn't been prettified yet. The url is here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/0000320193-18-000070.txt

Comment: And as far as {'text'} vs. {['text']} ... I haven't had an issue using the brackets. Might be unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick. Thanks all!

```
for item in soup.find('td', text='Trading Symbol').parent.find_all('td', {'class':['text']}):
    ticker = [item.text.strip()]
    print(ticker)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already at the level of td.
If you want the code snippet to work try

```
for td in items.parent.find('td', {'class':['text']}):
```

Answer (score 0):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :contains along with general sibling combinator to get those tds

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/0000320193-18-000070.txt')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
siblings = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('td:contains("Trading Symbol") ~ td')]
print(siblings)
```